# HTML Select-Option Two colors and name

Tags: html, css, angularjs, input

I have a list of color model to choose from, each having **name, background and foreground color**.

Is there a way to display an icon/box with two colors and name in the option? In dynamic way, not selecting images (or having a base image and then transform it -- change colors).

Values from server are like:

```
1;BlackOnWhite;#000000;#ffffff
2;WhiteOnBlack;#ffffff;#000000
```

and so on...

I have tried with css this: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7gcp6z89/1/) but thought to ask if there was a possibility to put a colored box in the selection list.

Thank you!

Comment: Show us what you've tried ?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?  What kind of html/input element do you want?

Comment: If you want help put some code .. !!

Comment: explain wat 'icon/box with two colors' exactly means

Comment: is it ok to flag this question 'in need of moderator intervention'?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want but I made a demo of what I think you want to do: https://jsfiddle.net/thepio/yy3Ljud6/. Not going to post this as an answer (and it's not a direct example but more of a general thing) unless you explain more about what you actually want.

Comment: @thepio thank you for angular example! I have edited my post, hope it is more verbose :)

Comment: @JonesJoseph: examples like selecting a language and you see the flag. I thought maybe with only two colors, it can be done in-place without images.

Comment: @Loading.. sure, just added fiddle link

Comment: @thepio you actually answered my question! Thank you! :) that's it! I've forked yours: https://jsfiddle.net/6z6b7o0t/1/

Comment: @OlehSky oh ok, if that's what you wanted. I just posted an answer of what I actually thought you wanted after your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your fiddle I can come up with a solution.

HTML:

```
<div>
  <select>
    <option>Choose color</option>
    <option ng-repeat="checkbox in checkboxes" class="color-{{checkbox.foreground}}-{{checkbox.background}}">{{checkbox.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

If you want to remove the # from the HEX value you need to just alter the scope variable or do a filter etc. But let me still warn you that browsers have various or no support for giving CSS to a `<option>` element. If you want to style select elements you should try a plugin like Select2 or Chosen etc.

Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/thepio/joqdj2cr/

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help :)